# Having trouble creating a function to calculate product of elements in a list within a specific range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm tasked with writing a function to calculate the product of elements of a list between the nth and mth position.

I've tried writing the following code but I keep getting 'int' object is not subscriptable:

```
myList=[1,2,3,4,5]

total = 1

for x in myList:
    total = total * x

print(total[1:3])
```

---

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to make n = 1 and m = 3 and I'm trying to get 2*3*4

Comment: `total` is a number, so `total[1:3]` is trying to subscript a number. I believe you want `for x in myList[1:3]:` instead. You want to subscript the list, then find the product, not find the product, then try to subscript the product.

Comment: You should index 'myList' instead of 'total' which is of type int and therefore un-subscriptable. It would look like: for x in myList[1:3]

Comment: Thank you guys! That worked. But maybe I don't understand [1:3]... By writing [1:3] in the list, that should could 1 and 2 right? Because in a list it's inclusive?

Comment: `in a list it's inclusive?` try it in a shell prompt.

Comment: I'm sorry wwii, i don't think I understand what you mean? I'm asking if when I write [1:3], should they include (in my example), 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 2):

*You can use:*

```
def prod(A, n, m):
    arr = A[n:m + 1]
    if arr:
        res = 1
        for num in arr:
            res *= num
        return res
```

*OR,*

```
from functools import reduce

def prod(A, n, m):
    arr = A[n:m + 1]
    if arr:
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, arr)
```

*OR,*

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def prod(A, n, m):
    arr = A[n:m + 1]
    if arr:
        return reduce(mul, arr)
```

*Example,*

```
>>>print(prod([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1, 3))
24
```

Comment: I don't understand the prod (A, n, m) that you wrote... And what is arr?

Comment: @JamieSlattery `prod(A, n, m)` is the function definition, and `arr` is the identifier, i suggest you to read the basic constructs of pythons.

Comment: can you explain [1:3]? I thought in a list (in my example) that 1 is actually in the zero position. So [1:3] should include 2,3,4?

Comment: @JamieSlattery List Indexing  in python starts from `0` and yes [1:3] should include `2,3,4` but as you have asked in the question **that you want to multiple the list from n=1 to m=3 and you have produce the result 1*2*3** that's why i have adjusted the functions so that you can actually multiply elements by specifying indices from 1 to 3 which gives you result `1*2*3`

Comment: From my notes, it says that for n = 1 and m = 3 the result should be 2·3·4, for n = 0, m = 3 the result should be 1·2·3·4... am I not understanding something?

Comment: I'm looking to produce the correct results according to my list

Comment: @JamieSlattery  I will update the answer according to your  notes but please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Just updated it. For clarification:  I'm trying to make n = 1 and m = 3 and I'm trying to get 2*3*4

Comment: Hey thanks for the update, but I guess I'm trying to understand what to put in prod(A, n, m) still.. I'm sorry i literally started python two days ago

Comment: @JamieSlattery You don't have to put anything in function definition, you just have to call it to obtain the results, eg, if `n=1` and `m=3` then use `result = prod(mylist, 1, 3)` then you can display the output using `print(result)` which gives you `24`. Hope I am comprehensible.

Comment: Hi! I tried what you wrote and am getting this result:   def prod(myList, 1, 3):
                     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JamieSlattery your'e misunderstanding, please read the basics first.

Comment: @JamieSlattery Read the basics at this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized it should be def product(myList, n, m) and define n =1 and m = 3. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Ok I read through ti and I'm still getting the issue where I'm getting the invalid syntax in regards to def prod(myList, 1, 3)... But I do understand that I just have to print to call

Answer (score -1):

the syntax error is total[1:3] coz total is type integer.
maybe You meant to write print(total) ??

Comment: Yes, you're right, I adjusted it to... for x in myList[1:3]: ----- but can you explain the [1:3]? Should that include 1, 2, and 3 in the calculations?

Comment: No, myList[1:3] will give 2,3,4.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I put it into my formula, I get an output of 6

Comment: I am sorry, i was reading another example. the output in your case will be 2,3. please take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists. those things are sensible coz they are not the same between python 2 and 3;